# What is appStoreReceiptURL for?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I've just added an IAP to my iTunes, and added a test user, all that looks fine and IAP's are enambled for my game. In the Apple Docs it says to put this code in the AppDelegate

```
 // Locate the receipt
    NSString *receiptPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path];

    // Test whether the receipt is present at the above path
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:receiptPath]) {

        NSLog(@"Exit");
        // Validation fails
        exit(173);
    }
```

I don't quite understand what the point of that code is? when I run my game with that code in it, it just exits straight away, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html

Comment: Thanks,but I still haven't a clue what it's for, or why it's not working when I run it.

Answer (score 3):

The `appStoreReceiptURL` is a method used to provide the receipt needed to perform Receipt Validation ([Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2))

The method you describe for displaying the `exit(173)` code is specific to OSX and shouldn't be used on iOS7. Exiting the app with this code will make OSX attempt to refresh the receipt if it cannot be loaded at the path.

For iOS7 (not available before iOS7) you should instead use the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` class. This will force the receipt to be refreshed.